# React Native - FlatList Not Rendering

Tags: react-native, expo, custom-component, flatlist

(Note: I'm using Expo for this app)

I'm attempting to render a `FlatList` that displays a list of printers. Here's the code:

```
<FlatList
  data={printers}
  keyExtractor={printer => printer.id}
  renderItem={({ item }) => {
    return (
      <Printer
        printerTitle={item.name}
        selected={item.selected}
        last={item === last(printers)}
      />
    );
  }}
/>
```

Here's the code for the `<Printer />` component:

```
const Printer = props => {
  const { last, printerTitle, selected } = props;
  return (
    <View style={[styles.container, last ? styles.lastContainer : null]}>
      <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
        <View style={styles.leftContainter}>
          {selected ? (
            <Image source={selected ? Images.checkedCircle : null} />
          ) : null}
        </View>
        <View style={styles.printerDetails}>
          <Text style={styles.printerTitle}>{printerTitle}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

...

export default Printer;
```

I can't seem to get the `<Printer />` component to render. I have tried including a similar custom component (that has worked in a `FlatList` in another part of the app) in the `renderItem` prop, and it doesn't work either.

However, when I replace the `<Printer />` component with `<Text>{item.name}</Text>` component, the printer name renders like I would expect it to.

Has anyone run into this issue before, or does anyone have a solution?

Comment: What is the Printer component look like? How do you export it? How do you import it? Did you tried to put the rendered component in Printer directly into renderItem? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 28):

In my case, where I'm rendering a custom component for each item in the list, it wasn't rendering because I accidentally had `{}` surrounding the return part of the `renderItem` prop instead of `()`.

Changing:

```
<FlatList
  data={array}
  renderItem={({item, index}) => { <CustomItemComponent /> }}
/>
```

to this:

```
<FlatList
  data={array}
  renderItem={({item, index}) => ( <CustomItemComponent /> )}
/>
```

Solved my issues.

Comment: Yeah! This is the perfect solution

Comment: One of those you spend hours trying to see what's going on, and all you need is another set of eyes...

Comment: To be consistent, keep the braces and inside it do `return ( <CustomItemComponent/>);`

Answer (score 7):

I suspect there are two issues at hand: one is that your FlatList is not filling the screen (namely its parent view) and the other is that your Printer component is not being sized correctly.

For the first issue, put a style with `{ flex: 1 }` on your FlatList. This way it will fill its parent view.

For the second issue, try adding `{ borderColor: 'red', borderWidth: 1 }` to your Printer components, just so that you can more easily see where they're being rendered. If they seem like they have no width, make sure you haven't overridden `alignSelf` on the Printer component's root view. If they seem like they have no height, add `height: 100` temporarily just so you can see what the contents of the Printer components look like.

Within your Printer component, make sure to specify the width and height of your image on the Image component like `{ width: 40, height: 30 }` or whatever the dimensions of your image is in logical pixels.

Answer (score 5):

I have same problem.
Resolve with adding width to FlatList

```
render() {
    const dimensions = Dimensions.get('window');
    const screenWidth = dimensions.width;
    return(
      <FlatList
         style={{
             flex: 1,
             width: screenWidth,
         }}
       ... some code here
      />
    )
}
```

Comment: This was it for me. Added Width: '100%' in the styling and it worked

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the `keyExtractor` in this way, make this function like below. It might solve your problem.

```
_keyExtractor = (item, index) => index;
```

If you update your question with you printer component code we can help  you better.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I accidentally made it a pair tag: `<FlatList></FlatList>`, which for some reason breaks rendering of list items.

Answer (score 0):

in my case Container was not having width of 100%:

```
const Container = styled.View`
  border: 1px solid #ececec;
  margin-top: 43px;
  padding-top: 36px
  padding-bottom: 112px;
  width: 100%;
`;

const StyledFlatList = styled(
  FlatList as new () => FlatList<SimilarRewards_viewer['merchants']['edges'][0]>
)`
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  flex: 1;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
`;
```